# Error in Django send_mail function?

Tags: django, django-email

I am trying to use send_mail from Django Documentation:

```
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@gmail.com',
['to@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

I am using the real e-mail address. However I get this error:

```
send_mail() takes exactly 1 non-keyword argument (4 given)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function call has correct arguments according to Django's docs. `send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None, auth_password=None, connection=None)`
Are you sure you don't have another function named `send_mail` in your file?

Comment: Oh I got it! I shouldn't have named the view show_file. Thanks mate!